# Calling a refresh function does not cause a display of the updated bound list but a button calling the same function does

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, refresh, viewmodel

I am quite new to WPF and I apologise for the rookie mistakes in advance.

I am working on a larger piece of code and I want to cause a refresh in a list when a file is added to a folder. In that particular page there already is a refresh button that triggers the update function and it works but when I try to call it from outside that viewmodel it does not cause the refresh although it runs through every step of the process. The main point is that although the list is refreshed when called from both directions it is only displayed in the updated version if called from the button.

So far I have tried to change the permissions,the order for the property change trigger and to raise a simulated button click

In all those situations everything works fine and it runs and finishes the updating process but the new item does not automatically appear

Any idea why it doesn't work?

here are the respective bits of code

```
<Button x:Name="RefreshButton" Content="Refresh" Width="Auto" Margin="5" Click="RefreshCommand"/>
```

And the cs

```
  private void RefreshCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        var dc = (ViewModelPage)btn.DataContext;
        dc.RefreshAndFilterList(); // this is the refresh and filter function which works on its own 
    }
```

Here is the list xaml

```
 <ListView Name="SnapsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesContainer.CompleteImagesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding ImagesListSelectedItem}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="listFiles_MouseLeftButtonDown" SelectionChanged="listFiles_SelectionChanged" >
```

This is the way I am calling it when a notification of a new file is received from outside the viewmodel.

```
ViewModelPage.RefreshTS = !ViewModelPage.RefreshTS;

    private bool _RefreshTS = false;
    public bool RefreshTS
    {
        get
        {
            return _RefreshTS;
        }
        set
        {

            _RefreshTS = value;
            RefreshAndFilterList();

            NotifyPropertyChanged();}


       }
```

EDIT
Added the Notify method

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding has no effect. You should not set it.

Comment: Besides that, are you sure that both code parts operate on the same ViewModelPage instance? When you call `ViewModelPage.RefreshTS`, is that ViewModelPage the same object that is in the DataContext of your Button?

Comment: Can you post your NotifyPropertyChanged method?

Comment: @LordWilmore I added it to the post

Comment: @Clemens Yes I am sure. I have tried to go through the button method itself by simulating a click event and the updated list was not displayed even though the item was added. Also thanks for the advice

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in your output window when it fails?

Comment: @LordWilmore it throws no exceptions as it runs through every bit of the refresh function code and updates it. The problem is that the change does not become visible in the displayed list